# counting prime numbers infinite loop

Tags: c

I tried counting how many prime there are (except 1 and 0) until there are N number of primes. But somehow my program always ends up looping **INFINITELY**

```
int main (){
    int n; 

    printf("Enter size N: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int i, j, ctr = 0, flag = 0; 
        for (i = 2; ctr != n; i++){
            for (j = 2; j < i; j++){
                if (i%j==0){
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag!=1){
                ctr++;
            }
        }
    
}
```

Comment: The condition for the `i` loop should probably be `i <= n`, instead of `ctr != n`.

Comment: The program doesn't look for prime number between 2 and `n`. It looks for `n` prime number from 2 to whatever needed to have `n` primes (yeah it is confusing, as most of the time people look for the first solution)

Comment: 1 and 0 are by definition not prime, so excluding them is exactly correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice you never reset your flag.
So once a divider is found, you raise your flag to indicate it isn't a prime.
But never set it back to 0, so all number afterward are considered `not prime`

```
int i, j;
int ctr = 0; // Prime number counter
int flag; 
// For i, from 2 to whatever needed to have N prime numbers
for (i = 2; ctr != n; i++){

    flag = 0 // THIS IS THE LINE YOU'RE MISSING

    // Look for potential divider
    for (j = 2; j < i; j++){
        // If i is divided by j, it isn't prime
        if (i%j==0){
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    // If no divider found, i is prime
    if(flag!=1){
        ctr++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could also move that into the `for`, like `++i, flag = 0`.

Comment: Exactly, `flag` is linked to the logic of the loop. So it is relevant to add it there.

Comment: Ohh! Now I get it! Thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 0):

To add something to your program different than what Portevent mentioned, you dont have to check if `i % j != 0` for all  `j < i` to check if `i` is prime. You just have to check for the range `j < sqrt(i)`.
This is because you stop looping when you get a `j` value such that `i % j == 0`. If you were to get to `j == sqrt(i)` it means for `i` to not be prime it would have at least a prime factorization of `p * q` with `p` and `q` being greater than `sqrt(i)`, which is nonsense, hence `i` is prime.
PS: in case you add this optimization to your program, do not hardcode `sqrt(i)` in the for loop, assign it to some variable then write the variable in the loop to avoid repeated computations.

Comment: Heres a [useful link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63276/is-a-prime-factor-of-a-number-always-less-than-its-square-root) if you want to know more.

Answer (score -1):

Who told you that your program loops infinitely? It doesnt.
You just missed resetting the flag like others specified. And also:

you can loop for j < i/2;

Think about it: what is the biggest integer divisor of a prime/non-prime number other than self?

To find it out divide it by the possible minimum integer number:

if we divide it by 1 we get the number itself *

if we divide it by 2 we get the half of the number which is the possible maximum divisor.

Comment: There is upper boundary for INTEGER dividers ...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).